# Acces to viewController from a pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

On a sight I have a PickerView and a button. Depending on the choice in the pickerview (I have 4 lines) I would like clicking on a button to go on a specific view. Now, whatever my choice is, I'm always on the same view (saline). Below is my code of the controller. If anyone can help me understand my mistake?

```
import UIKit

class SommaireGeneralViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    var PlacementAnswer = 0

    var liste = ["Sommaire général", "Région Est", "Région Ouest", "Région Sud", "Région Nord"]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return liste[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return liste.count
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let titleData = liste[row]
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 10.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
            return myTitle
    }

    @IBAction func Voir(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (PlacementAnswer == 0) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Saline", sender: self)


        } else if (PlacementAnswer == 1){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("1", sender: self)

            return

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
          PlacementAnswer = row

    }

    func prepareForSegue(id: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if "Saline" == id.identifier {

        }
        else if "1" == id.identifier {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you connected your @IBAction with the storyboard event? You may want to try and put a breakpoint inside `@IBAction func Voir(sender: AnyObject) {` to verify if the method ever gets called.

Comment: Please add `print(row)` in `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent)` method. `UIPickerView` standard selection behavior is pretty ugly, lets see if delegate method called as you expected

Comment: because when you press your button didSelectRow never fires

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have added "Print Row" and I still have the same reaction I'm always on the same view (saline)

Comment: Any prints in console when you selecting row?

Comment: The prints when select the second "Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful."

Comment: Please provide relevant information or we will not able to help you.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. In the console that I have messages on the constraints of my tableview destination (Saline)

Comment: Do you able to pick rows in pickerView? When pick, do you wait until animation is done?

Answer (score 0):

Hello, finally it's working, I put the code that can be used for others.
Cheers and thank you again for the info

```
import UIKit

class SommaireGeneralViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,     UIPickerViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

enum ActionSheetTag: Int {
    case ActionSheet0
    case ActionSheet1
}

var PlacementAnswer = Int()

let liste = ["Sommaire général", "Région Est", "Région Ouest", "Région Sud", "Région Nord"]

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return liste[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return liste.count

}



func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int,  forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = liste[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes:   [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 10.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
        return myTitle
}


@IBAction func Voir(sender: AnyObject) {


    if (PlacementAnswer == 0) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Saline", sender: self)


    } else if (PlacementAnswer == 1){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Autre", sender: self)

    }

  }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if let tag = ActionSheetTag(rawValue: row) {
            switch tag {
            case .ActionSheet0:
                PlacementAnswer = 0
            case .ActionSheet1:
                PlacementAnswer = 1


}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You tried tag and enum? If your answer is no, try this and return the output to me.

```
enum ActionSheetTag: Int {
        case ActionSheet1
        case ActionSheet2
}
```

.
.
.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if let tag = ActionSheetTag(rawValue: pickerView.tag) {
            switch tag {
            case .ActionSheet1:
               PlacementAnswer = 0
            case .ActionSheet2:
               PlacementAnswer = 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just put the code shown but nothing changes I always go to the same view (saline)

Comment: Well so.. it seems there is no fault in your picker codes. The reason of this error should be in your button or pickerview's delegate and datasource connections. You can recreate your picker with this example: [link](http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-uipickerview-example-using-swift/)

Comment: thank you board, I went to see you and keep informed